# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method...)

Tags: flutter

I have an existing Flutter app that I use to prototype and test ideas before adding the idea to a project. I need a custom plugin to track location in the background for a project so I added plugin related code into the  normal app project.
I am targeting android for a start. I have a Dart class representing the plugin that creates a method a channel to communicate with the platform code. On the platform side, I have created a class that extends `FlutterPlugin`
However, when I run the app and Dart native code calls methods on the Android side using the method channel, I get `Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException`.

Here's the code

## Dart code

```
class GeofencePlugin {
  final MethodChannel _channel =
      const MethodChannel('marcel/geofencing_plugin');

  Future<bool> init() async {
    //callbackDispatcher is a top level function that acts as entry point for background isolate
    final callback = PluginUtilities.getCallbackHandle(callbackDispatcher);
    await _channel
        .invokeMethod('GeofencingPlugin.initialiseService', <dynamic>[callback!.toRawHandle()]);
    return true;
  }

  Future<bool> registerGeofence(GeofenceRegion region) async {
    return true;
  }

  Future<bool> removeGeofence(GeofenceRegion region) async {
    return true;
  }
}
```

## Android code

```
class GeofencingPlugin : ActivityAware, FlutterPlugin, MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler {
    private var mContext : Context? = null
    private var mActivity : Activity? = null
    private val geofencePendingIntent: PendingIntent by lazy {
        val intent = Intent(mContext, GeofenceBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        private val TAG = "MARK_TAG"
        @JvmStatic
        val SHARED_PREFERENCES_KEY = "com.example.flutter_playground.geofencing"
        @JvmStatic
        val CALLBACK_DISPATCHER_HANDLE_KEY = "callback_dispatch_handler"


        @JvmStatic
        private fun initialiseService(context: Context, args: ArrayList<*>?) {
            val callbackHandle = args!![0] as Long
            context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                .edit()
                .putLong(CALLBACK_DISPATCHER_HANDLE_KEY, callbackHandle)
                .commit()
        }
    }

    override fun onAttachedToEngine(binding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
        mContext = binding.applicationContext
        val channel = MethodChannel(binding.binaryMessenger, "marcel/geofencing_plugin")
        channel.setMethodCallHandler(this)
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromEngine(binding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
        mContext = null
    }

    override fun onAttachedToActivity(binding: ActivityPluginBinding) {
        mActivity = binding.activity
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromActivity() {
        mActivity = null
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromActivityForConfigChanges() {
        mActivity = null
    }

    override fun onReattachedToActivityForConfigChanges(binding: ActivityPluginBinding) {
        mActivity = binding.activity
    }

    override fun onMethodCall(call: MethodCall, result: MethodChannel.Result) {
        val args = call.arguments<ArrayList<*>>()
        when(call.method) {
            "GeofencingPlugin.initialiseService" -> {
                initialiseService(mContext!!, args)
                setupGeo()
                result.success(true)
            }
            else -> result.notImplemented()
        }
    }

    private fun setupGeo(){
        val geofencingClient = mContext!!.getGeofenceClient()
        val fence = Geofence.Builder()
            .setRequestId("Mark")
            .setCircularRegion(46.5422,14.4011,500f)
            .setExpirationDuration(600000)
            .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER or Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
            .build()
        val request = GeofencingRequest.Builder().apply {
            setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_DWELL)
            addGeofences(listOf(fence))
        }.build()
        geofencingClient.addGeofences(request, geofencePendingIntent)?.run {
            addOnSuccessListener {
                Toast.makeText(mContext,"Hahaha", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            addOnFailureListener {
                Log.d(TAG,it.message?:"Eoo")
                Toast.makeText(mContext,"Heeerrrh", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the following

1. Manually adding the android plugin class to the GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java file
2. Using `flutterEngine.plugins.add('my plugin')` in the `MainActivity`'s `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 0):

After digging into the pubsec.yaml of other plugins, I found out in order to have my app's plugin recognised by flutter I have to add the following to my pubsec.yaml under the `flutter` section:

```
plugin:
platforms:
  android:
    package: com.example.flutter_playground.geofencing
    pluginClass: GeofencingPlugin
```